# Android browsers render dart webpages but webviews do not

Tags: dart

When I load a dart generated webpage from android browsers it renders perfectly. When I try to render on webview, images do not load. Any ideas how to render same webpage on webview?

Android version : same situation on api 8 15 and 17

javascript (dart2js output) gives uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'constructor' of null

I think this is because images never loaded.

I set all the permissions on webview.
I set chrome client.
I set webview client as well

```
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    engine.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    engine.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    engine.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    engine.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); 
    engine.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Kitkat (4.4), the WebView was not based on Chrome. Based on the date of this post, my guess is that was your problem.

From 4.4 onwards, there is a Chrome-based WebView, but it's still not completely the same as Chrome. There are some details on the differences and what's supported on the Chrome developer site here:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't have the setup to confirm that there was not another reason for the problem.